# How to Authenticate a Service Account for the Gmail API in Node Js?

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-iam

So I'm using the Node.js Gmail library to send an email to another user. I was thinking of using a Service account to do just that. I've followed their [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#using-the-keyfile-property) of passing the `keyFile` property but when I try to run the code, I get a `401` error, `Login Required`.

Here's what I got so far:

```js
const { gmail } = require("@googleapis/gmail");

function createMessage(from, to, subject, message) {
  // logic that returns base64 email
  const encodedMail=[...];
  return encodedMail;
}

export default function handler(req, res) {
  const auth = gmail({
    version: "v1",
    keyFile: './google_service.json',
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"],
  });

  const raw = createMessage(
    process.env.SERVICE_EMAIL,
    "someone@gmail.com",
    "Subject",
    "This is a test",
  );


  const post = auth.users.messages.send({
    userId: "me",
    requestBody: {
      raw,
    },
  });

  post
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

}
```

I've already got my Service Account credential json file and placed it at the root of my project. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What type of email account are you trying to access - Gmail or Workspace? For Gmail accounts - not possible. For Workspace, you must set up Domain Wide Delegation and then impersonate a user.

Comment: Ah well that sucks. Was looking to use a regular Gmail account. Thanks for the info, though.